# How to override a function inside of a Trait?

Tags: 8

My goal is to override the function isApprovalRequired() in a Trait for the module Social Auth (social_auth). The file:

```
modules/contrib/social_auth/src/SettingsTrait.php
```

has a function (along with variables and other functions):

```
namespace Drupal\social_auth;

use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\user\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

/**
* Helper methods for Social Auth and Drupal settings.
*/
trait SettingsTrait {
  ...
  protected $configFactory;
  ...
  protected function isApprovalRequired() {
```

that I would like to overwrite. How do I overwrite JUST that one function in my own module? I've done similar things with classes before, but not sure what to do with a Trait.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939166/how-to-override-trait-function-and-call-it-from-the-overridden-function

Answer (score 0):

For those that may run across this. I could not find a way to override (don't think it's possible). I did eventually settle on modifying the line of the file myself, running a git diff, and adding my own patch to my composer.json. In this way, I can run updates and use composer correctly. It's not a patch others will need, but how it was solved might help others.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939166/how-to-override-trait-function-and-call-it-from-the-overridden-function